# Mapping Alt+n to pagedown in vim

Tags: vim

I want to map the Alt+n key combination in insert and escape mode to pagedown (moving down by large amount of lines) .
I have tried adding following lines to .vimrc file but not working.

```
:map <M-n> <PageDown>
:map <A-n> <PageDown>
:imap <M-n> <PageDown>
:noremap <A-n> <PageDown>
```

Is there some way I can map Alt+(some alphabet) (not a system key binding) to other key in vim ?

Comment: Oops, sorry missed  http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key . The solution in the link is working .

Comment: Correct, [vi.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) is the best place to search, and post questions on Vim.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping Alt+Tab in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885979/mapping-alttab-in-vim)

Comment: @SibiCoder, thought Alt+Tab is a system binding, however I think Alt+n and Alt+(some alphabet) are not. I've edited the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution afterwards at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key .
When Alt+alphabet is pressed, characters sent by the keyboard are ^[+key , so we first map the Alt+key to it's corresponding equivalent and then use noremap.

For example to map Alt+n to pagedown, this will word

```
execute "set <M-n>=\en"
nnoremap <M-n> <PageDown>
```